# How to view all characters of a font and their letter mapping

Tags: fonts, embedded-fonts

So I got this icon font as .eot, .svg, .ttf and .woff for use in a web page.

So for example in my web page i would write `<i>t</i>` and assign `<i>` the icon font. In the icon font, the letter `t` is the icon I want to display here.

But there is no information which characters actually represent which icons.

So I wonder how if there is a way, or maybe some software, that would let me view all characters, together with what letter they are mapped to.

Comment: Yeah, was just about to post this exact same question - see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5715/how-to-view-a-ttf-font-file ; and in particular http://bluejamesbond.github.io/CharacterMap/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did find one app - it's a web application based on Django, [Glyphviewer](http://www.pkmurphy.com.au/glyphviewer/doc/) (https://github.com/peterkmurphy/glyphviewer). This is what I did on Ubuntu 14.04 in order to install it locally - note that the app in its current version is adapted to a CMS called Mezzanine, which I will not install here, so that is why the installation is a bit more involved.

First, you need this (I am using Python 2.7 here):

```bash
sudo apt-get install python-numpy     # (for python 3, python3-numpy)
sudo apt-get install python-pip       # (for python 3, python3-pip)
```

Then, install these dependencies:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/behdad/fonttools.git ;
cd fonttools ;
sudo python2 setup.py install ;
# ... log ends with: Finished processing dependencies for fonttools==3.0
cd ..

git clone https://github.com/typesupply/woffTools.git
cd woffTools
sudo python2 setup.py install
# ... log ends with: Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/woffTools-0.1beta.egg-info
cd ..
```

Then, install `glyphviewer` itself:

```bash
sudo pip install glyphviewer
# goes to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glyphviewer; also downloads+installs Django>=1.0
# ... log ends with: Successfully installed glyphviewer Django; Cleaning up...
```

Now, create your local application:

```bash
cd /tmp
django-admin startproject myglyphviewer
cd myglyphviewer/

# "The next stage is to add "glyphviewer" to your INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py"
python -c "import re; f=open('myglyphviewer/settings.py','r'); fs=f.read(); print re.sub('(INSTALLED_APPS = \(.*?)\)',r\"\1    'glyphviewer',\n)\",fs,flags=re.DOTALL)" > tmpset
mv tmpset myglyphviewer/settings.py
```

At this point, "... add the desired URL in one of the urls.py files."; so have this in your `myglyphviewer/urls.py` file:

```python
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
#from . import settings
import sys, os
sys.path.append( os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) ) 
#sys.path.append( "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-pac^Cges/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin" ) # base.html - via symlink 
import glyphviewer
from glyphviewer import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^glyphviewer/$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^glyphviewer/doc/$', views.doc, name="doc"),
]
```

We are going to use the admin `base.html` from Django, so do this:

```bash
sudo cp \
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html \
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/base.html
```

EDIT: we should copy here, instead of just symlink, because after the copy, we should edit the copied `base.html`, and insert:

```html
{% block extra_css %}{% endblock %}
```

... somewhere in the head; this comes from the [mezzanine/base.html](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/core/templates/base.html), and without it, the font will not be applied on the page!

Then, change these template files so they refer to "block content" instead of "block main":

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glyphviewer/templates/glyphviewer/doc.html`:

```html
{% block content %} <!--block main -->
```

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glyphviewer/templates/glyphviewer/index.html`:

```html
{% block content %} <!-- block main -->
```

Now,

```bash
# "The final stage is to populate the directory with fonts where you display your chosen font or fonts"
echo "STATIC_ROOT = '/tmp/myglyphviewer/static'" >> myglyphviewer/settings.py
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Now we should in principle be able to run the server, but if it fails with "*You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.*", then run:

```bash
python manage.py migrate
```

And finally we can run the server (again, all of this is done in the `/tmp/myglyphviewer` directory):

```bash
python manage.py runserver
```

If all went well, you should be able to point your web browser to http://127.0.0.1:8000/glyphviewer/ - and the app will be shown. Then, for the fonts inside your STATIC_ROOT, you will have a dropdown; there you could choose the font, then check "Shows characters in font", and click "Submit" - and after a while, you should get the table with characters; on my box, it looks like this:

[image: glyphviewer]

I've cut the table from the screenshot, as it is too long - but it shows enough that the app, with the described install process, should be working.

EDIT: if you'd want to inspect your own .woff fonts, it seems that you have to copy them both to the local "site" directory (here, `/tmp/myglyphviewer/static/glyphviewer/fonts/`) and the installation directory (`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glyphviewer/static/glyphviewer/fonts/`) - otherwise the system might return 404 when accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/glyphviewer/fonts/myfont.woff ...

Otherwise, if you don't care about local running, then you can also use the home http://www.pkmurphy.com.au/glyphviewer/ link, to generate the font glyph tables there (but only for fonts locally present there, or present somewhere on the net where they can be loaded from).